# Pass another argument to functor's library

Tags: c++, functor

I would like to pass another argument to a function from libtins library like that :

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(dates); i++) {
    FileSniffer sniffer("/path/" + dates[i] + ".pcap");
    sniffer.sniff_loop(doo, i);
}
```

So that I can use parameter i in my function like that:

```
    bool doo(PDU &pdu, int i) {
    const IP &ip = pdu.rfind_pdu<IP>();
    files[i] << ip.src_addr() << std::endl;
    return true;
```

However, this is not possible as the function sniff_loop is defined in the library and takes only one argument. In this case, should I modify the function's behavior, or is there a better solution to recover i in function sniff_loop?

Comment: Hopefully, dates is an array of signed or unsigned char...

Comment: @Aconcagua the overloaded `+` operators show that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes just just use a lambda

```
sniffer.sniff_loop([i] (PDU &pdu) -> bool {
    doo(pdu, i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> or is there a better solution?

If the library can work with a callable object, such as a functor, a lambda, or a `std::function`, there are elegant solutions. If not, you'll need to:

1. Store `i` in a variable in a suitable scope so that yourcall back function can use it.
2. Define a callback function that matches the signature of the function required by the library. Use that function in the call to the library.
3. Call the function you posted from the previous function using the value of `i` stored in the other variable.

---

```
bool doo_2(PDU& pdu);
static int loop_variable = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(dates); i++) {
    FileSniffer sniffer("/path/" + dates[i] + ".pcap");
    loop_variable = i;
    sniffer.sniff_loop(doo_2);
}

bool doo(PDU& pdu, int i) {
   const IP &ip = pdu.rfind_pdu<IP>();
   files[i] << ip.src_addr() << std::endl;
   return true;
}

bool doo_2(PDU &pdu) {
   doo(dpu, loop_variable);
}
```

---

From [the link you posted in a comment](http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/sniffing/#loop-sniffing)

> This method takes a template functor as an argument, which must define an operator with one of the following signatures:

That indicates to me that you should be able to use a lambda function.

```
auto fn = [i] (PDU& pdu) -> bool { return doo(pdu, i); };
sniffer.sniff_loop(fn);
```

Comment: Thank you. Yours and @Aram solution throw a "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'  what():  std::bad_alloc".
So your solution may work and there may be an error in my code.

Comment: Thank you. Your three solutions are working, I was just opening too many files at a time. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `std::bind`

```
#include <functional>

bool doo(PDU &pdu, int i) {
    const IP &ip = pdu.rfind_pdu<IP>();
    files[i] << ip.src_addr() << std::endl;
    return true;
}

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(dates); i++) {
    FileSniffer sniffer("/path/" + dates[i] + ".pcap");
    sniffer.sniff_loop(std::bind(&doo, std::placeholders::_1, i));
}
```